# Error VB.NET index out of bounds

Tags: vb.net

I am in a kind of situation here. I have an "index is out of bounds" error and I don`t know what causes it. I guess it has something to do with the tags.

Normally the tag represents a number. If I divide that number by the number of columns, it gives me back the row of the button that I clicked. If I take the mod of that tag it should return me the column of the clicked button. But something is wrong and I can`t figure out what. I hope someone can help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim AANTAL_KOLOMMEN As Integer = 8
    Dim AANTAL_RIJEN As Integer = 8
    Dim Button1 As Button
    Dim tel As Boolean
    Dim value1 As Integer
    Dim value2 As Integer
    Dim myButtons(AANTAL_RIJEN, AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) As Button



    Public Function zetNieuw(rij As Integer, kolom As Integer) As Button
        Dim nieuweKnop As New Button()
        nieuweKnop.Width = 40
        Me.Controls.Add(nieuweKnop)
        nieuweKnop.Name = "Btn_" & rij & "_" & kolom
        nieuweKnop.Left = kolom * nieuweKnop.Width
        nieuweKnop.Top = rij * nieuweKnop.Width
        nieuweKnop.Height = nieuweKnop.Width
        nieuweKnop.Text = ""
        AddHandler nieuweKnop.MouseDown, AddressOf Klik
        If rij = 3 And kolom = 3 Then
            nieuweKnop.BackColor = Color.Black
        End If
        If rij = 4 And kolom = 4 Then
            nieuweKnop.BackColor = Color.Black
        End If
        If rij = 3 And kolom = 4 Then
            nieuweKnop.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
        If rij = 4 And kolom = 3 Then
            nieuweKnop.BackColor =
                Color.White
        End If
        nieuweKnop.Tag = (kolom + (rij * AANTAL_KOLOMMEN))
        Return nieuweKnop


    End Function


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Me.value2 = 0 To AANTAL_RIJEN - 1 Step 1
            For Me.value1 = 0 To AANTAL_KOLOMMEN - 1 Step 1

                myButtons(value2, value1) = Me.zetNieuw(value2, value1)
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
    Private Sub Klik(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim knop As Button = sender
        Dim value As String = knop.Tag

        If myButtons(Tag / AANTAL_KOLOMMEN, (Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2).BackColor = Color.Black Or myButtons((Tag / AANTAL_KOLOMMEN - 2), Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN).BackColor = Color.Black Or myButtons((Tag / AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2, (Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2).BackColor = Color.Black Then
            knop.BackColor = Color.Black

        ElseIf myButtons(Tag / AANTAL_KOLOMMEN, (Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2).BackColor = Color.White Or myButtons((Tag / AANTAL_KOLOMMEN - 2), Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN).BackColor = Color.White Or myButtons((Tag / AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2, (Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2).BackColor = Color.White Then
            knop.BackColor = Color.Black
        End If



    End Sub




End Class
```

Comment: That error basically means that you are trying to use an index that is outside the range. Say you have 10 items in an array and you ask for item 13 it will blow up. Step through the code, and check to see how many elements you have and see what index you are calling.

Comment: Remember that array indexes in .Net start with 0, not 1.

Comment: Still can`t figure out what I`m doing wrong here. Have already spent a few hours on this and still can`t find it.

Comment: This line '(Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2' could be evaluating to -2, which would give you an index out of bounds error.  To find out, try just putting the number 1 or something in the place of this code and see if it runs.

Answer (score 1):

```
    If myButtons(Tag / AANTAL_KOLOMMEN, (Tag Mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN) - 2) ...
```

Using the Tag property is a *very* poor practice.  Just this one statement fragment has 3 bugs:

- It randomly indexes the wrong `rij` because it using floating-point division which then need to be rounded to make the index for the array.  Integer division is required, the `\` operator
- It uses the completely wrong Tag property, the one of the form instead of the button
- The reason for the -2 adjustment is hard to figure out but will certainly generate negative values.  This is what generates the exception.

Avoiding these kind of bugs requires a pretty fundamentally different programming style.  The one you'll acquire when you put `Option Strict On` at the top of the file and fix all the error messages you'll now get.  Beware that you'll get a lot of them, it will take a while to get it sorted.

And do stop using the Tag property.  The proper object-oriented way is to derive your own class from Button and add a `rij` and `kolom` property.  You can never get it wrong that way.

Comment: What can I use instead of the tag property. The assignment states i can use that tag to locate the button. But if I can`t use the tag, what can I use instead?

Comment: You didn't make it to the last paragraph in the answer?

Comment: Could you explain me how to do it?

Comment: Well, I did.  You can google "vb.net derive your own class" and find a lot more help.  First hit is already very good.